# when I import Mirror into unity I get this error: The type or namespace name 'ReadOnlySpan<>' could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I import mirror into unity im getting this error and I dont know how to fix it

```
Assets\Mirror\Runtime\NetworkReaderExtensions.cs(156,47): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ReadOnlySpan<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: are you using the right version? (2021.3.9 or higher)

Comment: I just Updated and it fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same error, so I updated unity to the most recent LTS 2021.3.11f1 and that fixed it.